# Grab word from sentences

Tags: php, regex

I want to grab words from sentences in PHP, for example in the following sentence:

> lorewm  "ipsum" dolor "sit" amet ...

I want to grab these two words:

> ipsum
>   sit

The sentences can be any length, I just want to grab all of the words surrounded by quotes (`""`).  Regex may be one acceptable way to do this.

Comment: What makes "ipsum" and "sit" special that they are the ones to be "caught" and not the other words?

Comment: not it is only example. the sentences will be changable. user inputs sentences then i will grab it:)

Comment: Daniel is asking because there's no way to help without knowing what it is you're trying to catch.  Literally the words "ipsum" and "sit"?  Or are there other factors?

Comment: Factor is  "". I should cath words with in this symbols "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
$input = 'lorewm "ipsum" dolor "sit" amet';
preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"/', $input, $matches);
```

Comment: i gave me Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier ']' :(

Comment: You don't need to make the quantifier lazy, and you need to add delimiters around your regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

And in your case preg_match_all()

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$subject = "ilorewm ipsum dolor sit amet ";
$pattern = '/ipsum|sit/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

the difference between my answer and the others is largely the pattern. Note the ipsum|sit. which matches either ipsum OR sit. also notice preg_match_all and not preg_match to match multiple occurrences, not just one per line.

note: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score -1):

Assuming what you mean is that you want to know if those two words are in the string, you should use PHP's strpos function. On some other languages, you'd use indexOf -- both methods return false/null/a negative number if the string isn't found.

In PHP, you'd do:

```
<?php
$pos = strpos($fullsentence,$word);

if($pos === false) {
  // the word isn't in the sentence
}
else {
  //the word is in the sentence, and $pos is the index of the first occurrence of it
}
?>
```

More info:
http://www.maxi-pedia.com/string+contains+substring+PHP

Comment: preg_match is clearly a superior method to accomplish this, and if you read the comments on the OP's post, you would have seen that he is looking for ANY words enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Oops. Misunderstood the question.